# Error 500 on Digital Ocean while using SwiftMailer to send email

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, digital-ocean

I am trying to send an email to myself from my seconday email address to my primary email address when a contact form is submitted to my website. I am using [Swiftmailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html) to achieve this. The code works perfectly when I use it offline on my XAMPP server on my computer, but when I try to run it on my Digital Ocean Droplet running a LAMP stack, which is almost identical to my offline setup, it doesn't work and returns an error 500.

I looked into it and it turns out, SMTP is disabled to prevent spam and it can be [lifted if I contacted support](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/smtp-impossible?answer=12486). After I contacted them, they told me they couldn't lift the restriction on port 25 but told me to try alternative ports and that SMTP doesn't work with Floating IPs. I removed my floating IP to help with this and I am currently trying to use port 578 with a Hotmail email address, but it still doesn't work.

What I have tried so far:

I used this command to open up the port 587 as suggested by Digital Ocean Support [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands#service-mail).

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 587 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

After that, my server is able to connect to smtp.office365.com at port 587 as showed by the command below:

```
nc -vz smtp.office365.com 587
Connection to smtp.office365.com 587 port [tcp/submission] succeeded!
```

The command "ufw status" shows that port 587 is open on both ipv4 and ipv6:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     LIMIT       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
3306/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
587/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                LIMIT       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
587/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But, when I try to run the contact form, it doesnt work in the end on the droplet, while it does work offline just fine and I received the emails as intended.

Is there something I am missing?

I will attach the code for my swiftmailer part below, just incase it helps identify any potential errors in the code that I seem to be missing.

```
include_once 'private/pass.inc.php';


//These fields usually get the data using a a form using POST method and PHP but left with placeholders here for the sake of simplicity.
$name = 'name';
$email = 'email';
$phone = 'phone';
$subject = 'subject';
$message = 'message';

// Send Email
// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.office365.com', 587, 'tls'))
    ->setUsername($emailusername)
    ->setPassword($emailpassword);

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

function sendVerificationEmail($name, $email, $phone, $subject, $message)
{
    global $mailer;
    $sentfrom = "secondary@example.com";
    $sentto = "primary@example.com";
    $body = 'Message From:' . $name . '<br>' . $email . '<br>' . $phone . '<br>' . $subject . '<br>' . $message;
    // Create a message
    $message = (new Swift_Message("A New Message From " . $name))
        ->setFrom([$sentfrom])
        ->setTo([$sentto])
        ->setBody($body, 'text/html');

    // Send the message
    $result = $mailer->send($message);
}

sendVerificationEmail($name, $email, $phone, $subject, $message);

echo "<script> window.location.assign('./contactformsuccess'); </script>";
```

EDIT: Added Logs

`[Sun Aug 15 07:34:58.851255 2021] [php:warn] [pid 182629] [client 162.158.167.91:37848] PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /var/www/site.com/html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php on line 94 [Sun Aug 15 07:34:58.851487 2021] [php:error] [pid 182629] [client 162.158.167.91:37848] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Unable to connect with TLS encryption in /var/www/site.com/html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php:349\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/site.com/html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php(148): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->doHeloCommand()\n#1 /var/www/site.com/html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mailer.php(65): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()\n#2 /var/www/site.com/html/includes/cf2.inc.php(39): Swift_Mailer->send()\n#3 /var/www/site.com/html/includes/cf2.inc.php(42): sendVerificationEmail()\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/site.com/html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/EsmtpTransport.php on line 349`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I had my Microsoft authenticator app connected to the secondary account I was trying to use, and it was throwing out errors because of that. I did not have 2 factor authentication enabled, but it was still causing issues so I disconnected it.

I also updated the swiftmailer transport with this:

```
// Create the Transport
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport('smtp.live.com', 587, 'tls'))
 ->setUsername($emailusername)
 ->setPassword($emailpassword)
 ->setStreamOptions(array('ssl' => array('allow_self_signed' => true, 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false)));
```

Both of these combined, solved my problem. Email goes through as intended now.